# Special characters in mod_rewrite url

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want this URL:

```
http://www.mydomainblabla.com/s/can+you+drill+shrinky+dinks?.html
```

to be rewritten to this one:

```
http://www.mydomainblabla.com/search.php?q=can+you+drill+shrinky+dinks?
```

I am using this mod_rewrite rule in my .htaccess to accomplish this

```
RewriteRule ^s/(.+).html$ search.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

However, the result is not as I want it, when I go to the first url, I get a page not found message.

The same problem occurs when I visit this url:

```
http://www.mydomainblabla.com/s/http://www.zakgeldnodig.nl/.html
```

which should be rewritten into this one:

```
http://www.mydomainblabla.com/search.php?q=http://www.zakgeldnodig.nl/
```

What modifications should I make to my .htaccess to make this work?

Comment: What should the rewritten URL look like?

Comment: @Miguel-F: As in the question? The order in which he presents them might be a little strange, but it's all there.

Comment: the rewritten URL has allow question mark and others special caracthers.

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding.  He gave examples of a URL and how it is being rewritten but they do not work.  I don't see an example of what the working URL should be once rewritten.

Comment: Sorry my not correct english Miguel. URL rewritten rule work if in query is not special caracthers. 

Example: http://www.mydomainblabla.com/search.php?q=car
url reweite is http://www.mydomainblabla.com/s/car.html

But if query is with question mark or others special caracthers, example:
http://www.mydomainblabla.com/search.php?q=car?
url rewrite is http://www.mydomainblabla.com/s/car?.html and not work

Comment: @Miguel-F I made a huge edit to the question, perhaps this makes it clear to you as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+s/(.+?)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ search.php?q=%1 [L,NE]
```